Line color for plotly with multiple traces
I am working with a dataset with 4 columns



Date
Category
Sub-category
Expenditure



I want to create a dashboard which shows expense vs date for select category and its subcategories. I get it the following way
cats = df.Category.unique()
tags={key: [] for key in cats}
for cat in cats:
    tags[cat] = df[df.Category==cat].Subcat.unique()

@callback(Output(graph,"figure"),Input(dropdown,"value"))
def update_bar_chart(cat):
    mask = df['Category']==cat
    fig = px.bar(df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum())
    for i, tag in enumerate(tags[cat]):
        mask = df['Subcat']==tag
        fig.add_traces(list(px.scatter(df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum()).select_traces()))
    return fig

However they all appear in the same color. How can I set line color for each trace, ie. different colors for different subcategories?

Plotly express graphs can be distinctly coloured passing the color argument to the plotly express function.
Refer: https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#colored-bars
You can try modifying your callback to something like below to distincly color the bar graph trace based on the Date (x axis).
@callback(Output(graph,"figure"),Input(dropdown,"value"))
def update_bar_chart(cat):
    mask = df['Category']==cat
    fig = px.bar(df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum(), color='Date')
    for i, tag in enumerate(tags[cat]):
        mask = df['Subcat']==tag
        fig.add_traces(list(px.scatter(df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum()).select_traces()))
    return fig


I have found a better way to achieve this with array and index objects of the dataseries obtained by grouping.
@callback(Output(graph,"figure"),Input(dropdown,"value"))
def update_bar_chart(cat):
    mask = df["Category"]==cat
    fig=px.bar(df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum(),opacity=0.7)
    for _i, tag in enumerate(tags[cat]):
        mask = df["Subcat"]==tag
        tdf=df[mask].groupby(df.Date)['Expense amount'].sum()
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=tdf.index,y=tdf.array,name=tag))
    fig.update_layout(title_text='Monthly expenditure towards '+cat,
        title_x=0.5, showlegend=True,legend_title=None)
    return fig

